# Get input from users until it's negative, and then calculate their sum.(using while loop)

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, while-loop, range

So the exercise is to get input from users until they enter a negative number and then calculate the sum of numbers before the negative one. (using while loop).

```
while True:
a = 0
summ = 0
while a >= 0:
    a = int(input("enter a number: "))
    summ = summ + a
    if a < 0:
        print(summ)
```

This was the code that I wrote for this exercise, but the problem is that it calculates the negative number too.
I'm pretty new to python, and this is one of the python exercises that I should do to learn more about algorithms.

Comment: the first line should (probably?) be deleted. then move the `summ = summ + a` down 2 lines. it should be below the `if` statement. and there should be a `break` inside the `if` statement. otherwise the loop continues.

Comment: add the negative no checkign condition below input

Answer (score 1):

```
allNonNegative = True
summ = 0
while allNonNegative:
    a = int(input("enter a number: "))
    if a >= 0:
        summ = summ + a
    else:
        allNonNegative= False
        print(summ)
```

Comment: I suggest using a more explicit name than `state`. `while state:` is not explicit at all. Something more explicit like `while allNonNegative:` would make it more clear what the stopping condition actually is.

Comment: suggestion accepted, answer edited

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an `if` at all. The condition is already checked by the `while`. No need to check it again inside the body.

Here are two alternatives to fix your issue.

#### First alternative: cancel the extra addition by a subtraction

```py
a = 0
summ = 0
while a >= 0:
    a = int(input("enter a number: "))
    summ = summ + a
summ = summ - a
print(summ)
```

#### Second alternative: only add nonnegative numbers

```py
prompt = "enter a number: "
summ = 0
a = int(input(prompt))
while a >= 0:
    summ = summ + a
    a = int(input(prompt))
print(summ)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need use IF statements to check negative values

```
summ = 0
while True:
    a = int(input("enter a number: "))
    if a < 0:
        break
    summ = summ + a
    print(summ)
```

Comment: You removed the condition from the `while`, to hide it as a `break` statement in the middle of the body of the loop. That's just obfuscating the code.

Comment: @Stef Is there an easier way to emulate a "do-while loop"?

Comment: I guess "easier" is mostly a matter of preference here. But look at the OP's code. At one glance it's immediately clear that the loop adds inputted numbers until a number is negative. The exact details, for instance whether the negative number is added to the sum or not, require a more attentive reading, but the main idea is immediately clear at a glance. With your code I feel it's the opposite - at a glance it's not obvious what's happening, because "while True" is not giving any hint. So your code needs to be read very carefully before we even know its main idea.

Comment: Note that using "while True / if break" was cited as a reason to reject the do-while PEP: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2013-June/021610.html . Still, using a clear condition makes the code so much easier to read, I think it's worth it.

Comment: Actually, you're calling `print` repeatedly inside the loop. The `print` should either be inside the `if` or outside the `while`.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I think I have not yet completely forgotten the convenience of the C language

Comment: I would like the user to see the sum immediately, and not after entering a negative value. I don't know what the author needs